# Updating multiple sheets from a user form

Tags: excel, vba

I have created two command buttons for the instruction to each sheet but the second one is not working, I think it may be a range issue but have tried a few things and it is not working.

This is a simple sales sheet (Sheet1) and stock sheet(StockData). I have put part of the sales data into the stock sheet and that is all working but when I update the information the second command button to update the info to the stock sheet is not working. I have been at it for days now and have tried as much as I can understand from suggestions on the internet.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

If txtLine.Text = "" Or cmbWHS.Text = "" Or cmbStatus.Text = "" Then
If MsgBox("Check Line or Warehouse or Status", vbCritical, "ERROR") = vbOK Then
Exit Sub
End If
End If

'to check the last filled row
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = txtInvoiceNumber.Text
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = txtLineNumber.Text
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = txtInvoiceDate.Text


Private Sub cmdSaleStockIn_Click()

'to check the last filled row
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("StockData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("StockData").Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = txtStockSaleNo.Text
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("StockData").Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = txtLineNumber.Text
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("StockData").Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = txtTransactionCdS.Text
```

' THese are working, but the update does not want to be as easy as that...
I have done the find and it puts all the data into the userform again

```
Private Sub cmdFind_Click()
Dim totalrow As Long
totalrow = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For currentrow = 2 To totalrow
If Trim(txtLineNumber) = Trim(Cells(currentrow, 2)) Then
txtInvoiceNumber.Text = Cells(currentrow, 1)
txtInvoiceDate.Text = Cells(currentrow, 3)
```

' This code is working

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
Dim totalrow As Long
totalrow = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For currentrow = 2 To totalrow
If Trim(txtLineNumber) = Trim(Cells(currentrow, 2)) Then
Cells(currentrow, 1) = txtInvoiceNumber.Text
Cells(currentrow, 3) = txtInvoiceDate.Text
Cells(currentrow, 4) = cmbCustomerName.Text
```

etc...
'so why not this one?

```
Private Sub cmdUpdStock_Click()
Dim totalrow As Long
totalrow = StockData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For currentrow = 2 To totalrow
If Trim(txtLineNumber) = Trim(Cells(currentrow, 2)) Then
Cells(currentrow, 5) = txtInvoiceDate.Text
Cells(currentrow, 7) = cmbWHS.Text
```

Comment: Please share with us the first few rows of each sheet, so that we can duplicate the problem.

Comment: `totalrow = StockData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` will work only when `CodeName` of  sheet is `Stockdata`. may use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("StockData").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count`. also it would be better to refer the cells like Cells(currentrow, 5) = txtInvoiceDate.Text `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("StockData")`. (in case the `StockData` is not active sheet)

Answer (score 0):

1st observation in the code (not working) is `totalrow = StockData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` will only work when `CodeName` of sheet is `StockData`.  This may be checked in the VBA properties window, the name of the particular Sheet displayed as `StockData`. may instead use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("StockData").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count`.

Also it would be always better to refer the cells like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("StockData").Cells(currentrow, 5) = txtInvoiceDate.Text` instead of `Cells(currentrow, 5) = txtInvoiceDate.Text`. The later may misbehave if the sheet is not Active Sheet.

further Defining the worksheet and using `With` is a better practice. so i tried the code portion like

```
Private Sub cmdUpdStock_Click()
Dim totalrow As Long
Dim wStock  As Worksheet
Set wStock = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stockdata")
With wStock
totalrow = wStock.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    For currentrow = 2 To totalrow
        If Trim(txtLineNumber) = Trim(.Cells(currentrow, 2)) Then
        .Cells(currentrow, 5) = txtInvoiceDate.Text
        .Cells(currentrow, 7) = cmbWHS.Text
    End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```

and working OK (as far i understand the way it is intended to work).

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try and let you know :)

Comment: It's working, Amazing, you're a genius, Thank you :)